# Problem with Restore-SPFarm

Tags: powershell, backup, web-application, restore

We have to move a Sharepoint 2010 web application from and old server to a new one.

The old server has Sharepoint 2010 and SQL Server both installed. The new server is actually 2 VMs, one for Sharepoint and another for SQL Server.

So, I had created a backup of the web-app using the cmdlet `Backup-SPFarm` in Sharepoint Management Shell. Uploaded the backup to the new server and executed the following command to restore it.

```
Restore-SPFarm -Directory C:\SPBackup -RestoreMethod new -NewDatabaseServer 374862-db1\sharepointdev
```

But it says:

> Restore-SPFarm : The restore job failed. For more information, see the
>   error lo g that is located in the backup directory. At line:1 char:15
>   + Restore-SPFarm <<<<  -Directory C:\SPBackup -RestoreMethod
>   new -NewDatabaseServer 374862-db1\sharepointdev
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData:
>   (Microsoft.Share...dletRestoreFarm:    SPCmdletRestoreFarm)
>   [Restore-SPFarm], SPException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletRestoreFarm

Checking the log I can see there are 2 Fatal Errors:

> Object SharePoint - Pilot failed in event OnRestore. For more
>   information, see the spbackup.log or sprestore.log file located in the
>   backup directory.  SPException: The specified user or domain group was
>   not found.
>
> Object WSS_Content_4010a143199e424eb76518b57b56c5c2 failed in
>   event OnRestore. For more information, see the spbackup.log or
>   sprestore.log file located in the backup directory.  SqlException: The
>   operation did not proceed far enough to allow RESTART. Reissue the
>   statement without the RESTART qualifier.

Any ideas to solve or workaround the problem are always welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: Why didn't you just add a database server to the existing farm and move the db files?

Comment: I'm not a Sharepoint expert and googling I found that command is the 'correct' way to backup and restore sites, but I'll try your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the backward compatibility commands **spsadm** to backup and restore the site.

Answer (score 1):

The error "The specified user or domain group was not found." is the likely culprit.  Make sure that the Farm Admin account is a local admin on the server you are trying to restore to.

Does the Farm Admin have full access to the new sql server?

Was this a single server install?  Is the server joined to the same domain?